# How to print a word after a phrase using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

It must be written in java using regular expression
I need to print a word after `"what is"`
Input:

```
So what is java regex
what is operator in java
```

Output:

```
java
operator
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a lookbehind to match a string which was just after to the string which matches the pattern inside the lookbehind.

```
(?<=what is )\\S+
```

OR

```
(?<=what\\sis\\s)\\S+
```

Code:

```
String s = "So what is java regex\n" + 
        "what is operator in java";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=what is )\\S+");
 Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
 while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Output:

```
java
operator
```

Answer (score 1):

If it must be regex, I would keep it simple and use a [capturing group](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html) to match and capture the word after "what is"

```
what\sis\s(\w+)
```

**Note:** You need to reference match group `#1` to return your match result.

Explanation:

```
what       # 'what'
\s         # whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
is         # 'is'
\s         # whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
(          # group and capture to \1:
  \w+      #   word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or more times)
)          # end of \1
```